# Programmatically Generate PDF Report with design

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, report

The background right now is that I coded website for the client and as part of the website I have a service calling a webpage every 5-10 minutes to generate some PDFS that become available on the website. The PDFs just contain a data dump of a table that is displayed on the website.

The new requirements are to add a cover page and apply a color scheme to the PDF report which replicates the view on the website.

I'm unsure how to go about this using C# and VS2008 with the backend database being MySQL. I originally thought about creating a report and then somehow programmatically rendering and saving it as a PDF, but because we are using MySQL that throws out the possibility of using Sql Server Reporting Services. Is there any other open source and/or free solution that will allow me to create and design the report and then programmatically create and save as a pdf without any user interaction?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is iText [here](http://itextpdf.com/).  It supports creating pdf programmatically in java or C#.  We use it where I work to do just this thing (also using MySQL on the backend).  I also recommend buying the book.  It has lots of good examples, and if you purchase the book, you get a pdf version of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Though written in PHP, it  has no external dependencies, has **plenty** of options and examples included. Works fast and reliable, no problems with fonts, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[jsreport](http://jsreport.net) supports exactly this kind of pdf generation. You first create a report layout and dynamic structure using html, css and javascript templating engines. Then you just send the data and invoke the rendering using c# classes.

This [blog post](http://jsreport.net/blog/pdf-reports-in-csharp) should give you more info how to do it.

Disclaimer: I am the author of jsreport.